# Can you use a weapon with two hands and it still count as a monk weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk, martial

Martial arts is a monk skill where, if you are using a monk weapon, you can attack with that weapon and also make an unarmed strike as a bonus action.

Monk weapons are shortswords and simple melee weapons that don't have the heavy or two-handed properties. But if you use a quarterstaff (which is a simple melee weapon that doesn't have the two-handed property) with two hands, could you still make an unarmoured strike as a bonus action?

Comment: Yes it does. It didn't show me that question when it was suggesting simular quaestions. This can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using two hands is not the same as the two-handed property

You can use two hands to make an attack with any weapon, say a dagger, but gain no benefit from doing so. The versatile property of quarterstaffs give a benefit for doing so and the two-handed property means you have to use two hands with the given weapon.

The requirement for monk weapons that they don't have the two handed property<sup>†</sup>, not that you don't use two hands for the attack.

† The heavy property is not relevant to the discussion, nor in general as there is no weapon with the heavy property and not the two-handed one.

## Unarmed attacks don't require a free hand

There's no rule saying unarmed attacks have to be made useing a free hand, and the general rule (PHB 195) even suggests them to be:

> a punch, kick, head-butt, or similar forceful blow (none of which count as weapons).

The Monk's Martial Arts make no modification to this, merely increasing the damage, letting you do more of them, and adding additional effects (particularly at higher levels).

Comment: The question could be paraphrased "if you use a quarterstaff two-handed, is it still a Monk weapon for triggering Martial Arts?", which this answer doesn't address.